# How to await until Task.ContinueWith inner task finishes

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, task

Take a look at this code:

```
    private async Task InnerTask(bool outerTaskResult)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2");
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(10000));
        Console.WriteLine("3");
    }

    private async void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var task = Task.FromResult(false);
        Task<Task> aggregatedTask = task.ContinueWith(task1 => InnerTask(task1.Result));
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        await aggregatedTask;
        Console.WriteLine("4");
    }
```

The desired output is:

```
1
2
3
4
```

But I get:

```
1
2
4
3
```

This probably has something to do with InnerTask being executed on a different thread.

I'm using ContinueWith because the tasks in the original code are dynamically created and queued this way.

Using *.Wait()* method (see below) works, but I think it's a bad idea, as the method is blocking.

```
task.ContinueWith(task1 => InnerTask(task1.Result).Wait())
```

What's the correct approach here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `TaskExtensions.Unwrap()` (which is an extension method on `Task<Task>`) to unwrap the outter task and retrieve the inner one:

```
private async void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var task = Task.FromResult(false);
    Task aggregatedTask = task.ContinueWith(task1 => InnerTask(task1.Result)).Unwrap();
    Console.WriteLine("1");
    await aggregatedTask;
    Console.WriteLine("4");
}
```

Note that to simplify this entire thing, instead of `ContinueWith` style continuation you can `await` on your tasks:

```
private async void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var task = Task.FromResult(false);

    Console.WriteLine("1");

    var result = await task;
    await InnerTask(result);

    Console.WriteLine("4");
}
```

Comment: `Unwrap` isn't actually needed. The return value of `await aggregatedTask` in the question is actually the inner task.

Comment: He has a `Task<Task>`, it's the outter task he's awating on, that's why it's completing *before* the outter `Console.WriteLine`. He can simply `await`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos True, it's not *needed*, one could also `await` twice.  Both would do the same thing.  This is certainly one appropriate approach.  In C# 5.0 you can actually implement `Unwrap` as: `public static async Task Unwrap(this Task<Task> task){ await await task; }` (The C# 4.0 version is actually annoyingly long and tedious.)

Comment: Note that your second snippet isn't strictly equivalent to the OP's code.  His code has a race condition allowing `1` or `2` to happen in either order.  Your second snippet enforces a strict ordering.  (Or to phrase it another way, it doesn't parallelize a few operations that the OP paralellized, and it may be the case that he wants those two operations to be able to happen in parallel.

Comment: @Servy You're right, i was *assuming* he wants the simplified case. It might not be so.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14402865/1159478) is an example of how one would have to go about implementing `Unwrap` in C# 4.0.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov You would only have to move the line printing `1` to be before `await task` (instead of being right after it) to maintain the OP's original semantics.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov And of course you need a version where the inner task is non-generic as well, which is pretty much a copy-paste and changing just two small expressions.